# Show currency in English language

Tags: uber-api

I am using ride request Widget. It is showing currency in Native language like Arabic. How cal I make it in English language?

I have used widget in XML.

Comment: To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: Can you also specify ios/android, sdk version, etc? XML assumes for android, but please be more clear in your questions and provide details.

Answer (score 1):

Using the ride request widget it is not possible to override the locale as it is determined by the http accept-language header that is set by the browser/os (since ride request widget is a web view).

Comment: Than you For your Answer.. any other way to do it..
I am using 
    compile 'com.uber.sdk:rides-android:0.5.3'

Comment: Not currently. You need to change the browser locale setting.